# How to run cordova application in the real device?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, apk

i'm beginner in development cordova android ,i want to run my application cordova in the real device by when i excute this command `cordova build android`  i found this error :

```
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/binov1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 127

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 29.066 secs
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: /home/binov1/workElolinkMobile/icooltaxi/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/binov1/workElolinkMobile/icooltaxi/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/binov1/workElolinkMobile/icooltaxi/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/binov1/workElolinkMobile/icooltaxi/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cordova platform add android

cordova platform build android
```

`adb devices` (check if your device appears in the list)

```
cordova run android
```

Comment: Error: Platform android already added.                                                                                                  root@binov1-HP-15-Notebook-PC:/home/binov1/workElolinkMobile/icooltaxi# adb devices
List of devices attached 
7F602C136346331 device

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `android sdk v.23.0.1`:

```
cd /home/binov1/android-sdk-linux/tools
./android
```

The Android SDK Manager window will open, and you need to select `SDK Platform API 23` and `Android SDK Build-tools`. If you want, you can install all `SDK Platform` and `Build-tools` of any API version.